# JsonConvert.SerializeObject in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Im retrieving data in database using ajax but when I'm calling the method in controller I getting an error in **JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings** and I don't know why. Here's my code:

Views

```
function EditRecord(Id) {
    var url = "/Admin/GetCategoryGroupById?Id=" + Id;
    $("#ModalTitle").html("Update Category Group");
    $("#MyModal").modal();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#Id").val(obj.Id);
            $("#Name").val(obj.Name);
            //$("#Status option:selected").text(obj.tblDepartment.DepartmentName);
            $("#cbStatus").val(obj.Status);
        }, error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    })
}
```

Controllers

```
    public JsonResult GetCategoryGroupById(int Id)
    {
        CategoryGroup model = db.CategoryGroups.Where(x => x.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
        string value = string.Empty;
        value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        });
        return Json(value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The error:

[image]

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i think that your db doesn't have any CategoryGroups with the specified id. this is why the singleOrDefault returns null. so you need to add an if statement to check weather model is null